# Cannot insert html code to an array

Tags: php, arrays

How to insert html code inside an array in PHP?

I tried searching on internet but found nothing.

```
$html = array
('<IFRAME src="http://link1.com" width="1" height="1" 
scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></IFRAME>' ,

'<IFRAME src="http://link2.com" width="1" height="1" 
scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></IFRAME>' ,

'<IFRAME src="http://link3.com" width="1" height="1" 
scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></IFRAME>');
print_r ($html);
```

When I tried to `print_r`, there was no result.

Comment: You sure there's no results? If you're doing the `print_r` onto a web page, the HTML will be interpreted as such ... right-click and view source to make sure ...

Comment: The way you built it is valid. It is working. And you say - 'there are no results'. What exactly do you get? Blank page, error, empty array...

Comment: @all

Yeah, Iam sorry that I forgoten to see it on source code... :(

anyways thank.. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no result because you are giving the output to the browser, which happily places three `<iframe>`s with invalid source URLs in your page. So you see nothing for the same reason you would see nothing if you did `print '<p></p>';`.

If you view the page source you will see your HTML is there.

Normally to see HTML markup as "plain text" you would need to pass it through `htmlspecialchars` -- however, that function works with strings and here you have an array. So if you want to print the contents as human-readable text, you need to do something fancier and use `array_map`:

```
print_r(array_map('htmlspecialchars', $html));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are printing these and accessing the output through your browser, you won't see any string as they are parsed by your browser.

If you would like to have a look at the raw output, do

```
echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($html, 1), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Yes, this would do it but he would need to loop through the $html array though.

Comment: crap, I got htmlspec and print_r in wrong order... Thanks stef

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem running the code you just posted. If you are outputting to a webpage the iframes are most likely there and you should just view your page source.  Try this...

```
<?php
    $html = array('<IFRAME src="http://link1.com" width="1" height="1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></IFRAME>',
    '<IFRAME src="http://link2.com" width="1" height="1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></IFRAME>',
    '<IFRAME src="http://link3.com" width="1" height="1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></IFRAME>');
    echo "<pre><code>";
    echo print_r ($html);
    echo "</code></pre>";
?>
```